# Should changeman demote delete the components from promotion libraries

Tags: mainframe, change-management

I promoted a new JCL 'TTTTS360' to TST( Promotion level 1). I noticed and JCL was created in ( as this is new JCL) in TTTTTST.E998.JCL(TTTTS360) and similarly entry was created in parameter lib 'COMPTST.AAAA.PARMLIB(QEEEEAU)'.

Now once I demote my package to level 0 i.e. development , I still see 'TTTTTST.E998.JCL(TTTTS360)', 'COMPTST.AAAA.PARMLIB(QEEEEAU)', shouldn't they be removed ? I was expecting them to be removed all together?

```
  I see following steps in changeman JOB 
      SYSPRINT DEL1CTC 
      SYSPRINT DEL1JCL

 DEL1CTC CHANGEMAN STEP
     DELETE QEEEEAU                           
     QEEEEAU  WAS DELETED FROM TARGET DATA SET
 DEL1JCL CHANGEMAN STEP
      DELETE TTTTS360                                  
      TTTTS360 WAS DELETED FROM TARGET DATA SET
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the libraries are. Anyway it will be determined how Changeman is set up.  You should speak to people where you work

Comment: Libraries are JCL library and Parmlib lib where are JCL and Parm should reside.

Comment: So those are the normal Test JCL / Parmlibs. Ok you could try trawling through all the messages Changeman spits out, there will probably be something in the messages. Also Changeman is very flexible try speaking to the administrator. Finally is there any problem if they are not deleted ????

Answer (score 2):

ChangeMan has the concept of "staging libraries" and "promotion libraries."  The former are sometimes referred to as "package datasets" because they are part of your ChangeMan package.

When you promote your package, typically the members from your staging libraries are copied to the corresponding target promotion libraries.  When you demote your package, the members that were promoted are deleted from the target promotion libraries.

Your staging libraries aren't cleaned up until after install and baseline have completed as part of your request to install in your production environment.   The cleanup may be days or weeks afterward, as a backout requires the staging libraries to be present.

Having said all that, ChangeMan is *very* configurable as Bruce Martin indicated in his comments.  Talk to your ChangeMan Administrator(s) about what behavior you should expect to see.